# for loop list index out of range

Tags: list, for-loop

I am reading a file, all data in the file is read and put in the list called "data" like below.
[‘43629’, '7’, ‘4’, ‘Runtime Error’, ‘0’, ‘879’, ‘12:20:52’],
[‘43628’, '31’, ‘3’, ‘Runtime Error’, ‘0’, ‘521’, ‘12:20:38’]...

I want to change the time type from str to class Time, but in the for loop the system shows list index out of range. The length of ['12','20','52'] is 3, why time[0], time[1], time[2] not workable?

```
class Time:
    def __init__(self, hour, minute, second):
        self.hour = hour
        self.minute = minute
        self.second = second

data = []
for line in file.readlines():
    line = line.strip('\n')
    line = line.split(',')
    data.append(line)


for i in (1, len(data)+1):
    time = data[i][6].split(':')
    data[i][6] = Time(time[0], time[1], time[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss two points.
One is missing `range` and the other is `i` must be in `0 ~ len(data) - 1`.

`(1, len(data) + 1)` is just a tuple.

```
for i in range(len(data)):
    time = data[i][6].split(':')
    data[i][6] = Time(time[0], time[1], time[2])
```